# How to click a js button in IE using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I want to create a code in ***Excel Vba*** to help me click a ***js image button*** in a website.

Here is what i have tried.

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
WebPage = "http://myweb.com"    'a makeup link, not really my site
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate WebPage
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tcSearchRoute_tabSearchRoute2_ibtnSearchR2").Click
End Sub
```

When I run the code, it says

RunTime Error '-2147217848(80010108)'
Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Here is the html code for that js image button

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tcSearchRoute$tabSearchRoute2$ibtnSearchR2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tcSearchRoute_tabSearchRoute2_ibtnSearchR2" src="../Images/button/btn_searchAccount.png" alt="Search Account" style="border-width:0px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.Click` line seems ok to me. Have you been using `ie.Quit`, before the `End Sub`, to close off instances each time you run your code? Check how many `InternetExplorer` instances you have running for starters.

Use a proper page load wait of:

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Then you could also try

```
ie.Navigate2 "http://myweb.com" & ie.Document.querySelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tcSearchRoute_tabSearchRoute2_ibtnSearchR2").src
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Or just retry you existing line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create and set IE object like below.

```
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    or try

 Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

        or try

 Set ie = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
```

You can try adding one of these wait loops after you set your IE object or anytime the IE page changes/refreshes.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 DoEvents
 Loop

While ie.busy
 DoEvents
 Wend

Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Further, you can try to disable the **enable enhanced protected mode** option in IE settings.

> Go to Tools-> IE options -> Advanced tab -> Security section - disable
>   "enable enhanced protected mode".

Reference:

[VBA Error:  The object invoked has disconnected from its clients](http://www.vba-market.com/2017/03/04/the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from-its-clients/)